# getting the last two tokens in batch script for command

Tags: scripting, ms-dos

I have a file name with fullpath and want to get the filename and the parent directory of the file.How can I parse this in batchscript?

e.g 
for /f "tokens=4,5 delims=\" %%a in ("F:\mydata\WebLogs\MyServerName001\u_ex100206.log")

in the above line token 4 is the servername and 5 is the filename.But this will not be always 4 and 5.So how can I get the last two tokens in a batch script?because in my scenario the filename will be the last token and the server name will be the token before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use %~nxI for the filename and use the code from the selected answer in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280969/windows-batch-loop-over-folder-string-and-parse-out-last-folder-name) for the parent folder.

Comment: you should at least clarify what %~nxl means, perhaps with an example and some output - its not necessarily obvious. I assume you actually mean %~nxa?

Answer (score 2):

The post pointed to by Helvick is over the top. 
Here is a simple way to get the parent dir (or the parent's parent dir, etc):

```
for /D %%I in ("F:\mydata\WebLogs\MyServerName001\u_ex100206.log") do (
   echo filename=[%%~nxI]
)
for /D %%I in ("F:\mydata\WebLogs\MyServerName001\u_ex100206.log\..") do (
   echo parent dir=[%%~nxI]
)
for /D %%I in ("F:\mydata\WebLogs\MyServerName001\u_ex100206.log\..\..") do (
   echo parent's parent dir=[%%~nxI]
)
```

... etc. The file does not need to exist.